# LUIS Builtin Entity Recognition on Blocks of Text

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

Is there any API in the cognitive services that will allow the application of the entity recognition function used in LUIS to blocks of text? (without the LUIS intent/command processing etc..)

I have tried the cognitive services "named entity recognition service", but it does not recognize the builtin entity types supported in LUIS. I have also tried setting up LUIS with a generic intent, but it has a 500 character query limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the dependency library [Recognizers-Text](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text).